# Outofmemory when I'm loading image with thumbnailload

Tags: c#, image, out-of-memory, thumbnails

When I'm trying to load image from my folder, I'm getting an :
`OutOfMemory`

I've got the following error when I've use MemoryStream :

```
 public ImageSource ThumbnailLoadAsync()
        {
            var imageTemp = File.Exists(Image) ? Image : string.Format("{0}\\img\\unknow.png", ImageFolderRoot);

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(imageTemp));
            ImageSourceConverter imageSourceConverter = new ImageSourceConverter();
            Thumbnail = (ImageSource)imageSourceConverter.ConvertFrom(ms);
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Thumbnail");
            return Thumbnail;
        }
```

Then, I saw a better version of MemoryStream which was RecyclableMemoryStreamManager but I also get the same error. Maybe I use it in the wrong way.

Here my code :

```
 private RecyclableMemoryStreamManager _imageRecyclableMemoryStream;
        public ImageSource ThumbnailLoad()
        {
            var imageTemp = File.Exists(Image) ? Image : string.Format("{0}\\img\\unknow.png", ImageFolderRoot);
            _imageRecyclableMemoryStream = new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();
            ImageSourceConverter imageSourceConverter = new ImageSourceConverter();
            Thumbnail = (ImageSource)imageSourceConverter.ConvertFrom((RecyclableMemoryStream)_imageRecyclableMemoryStream.GetStream(File.ReadAllBytes(imageTemp)));
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Thumbnail");
            return Thumbnail;
        }
```

Comment: How many times are you calling that method before you get OOM?

Comment: `_imageRecyclableMemoryStream = new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();` I suspect you want that `new` just once - not on every invocation.

Comment: Why are you using `MemoryStream` in the first place? `BitmapImage(new Uri(imageTemp));` should do the job I guess?

Comment: @mjwills I'm calling it just 5 times to load image. I have two classes (product and Category) which implement this methods.

Comment: Why are you using a `MemoryStream` rather than passing in a `FileStream` or using https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/235637/WPF-property-problem-ImageSource-vs-BitmapImage ?

Comment: You need to dispose of any stream, best by putting it in a `using` clause. How large are the images?

Comment: @MatJ I'm not using  ```BitMapImage``` because it doesn't display the picture that I need

Comment: @TaW That is _generally_ true - but it won't help with a memorystream.

Comment: @mjwills Yes just a once, to be able to have more memory in the heat memory system

Comment: Sorry, my english isn't good. You told me that I want ```...= new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager(); ``` just once, and I told you yes because every instance of this object is stored in the Heat. And if I do only one ```new```, it coulds probably avoid the out of memory

Comment: Gotcha - yes, that is what the below answer basically shows. I mean I think it is the wrong approach (since you read the data from a file into a memorystream, when there are simpler alternatives - like passing in the filestream instead).

Comment: @mjwills Yes you're right, I'm going to try passing directly in the filestream

Comment: @OlivierRogier Those duplicates seem to be about Bitmap / Image, which isn't what the OP needs.

Comment: @harili Did using filestream fix the issue?

Comment: @mjwills No the images don't appear, I'm still trying to understang why.I retrieve the path of each image, but it doesn't work

Comment: I've tried to use BitMapImage, but the same thing happens. 
@OlivierRogier No, not working

Comment: Please share a dotnetfiddle of your "new" code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to allocate the memory stream only once and use a using block...something like...

```
private static readonly RecyclableMemoryStreamManager recyclableMemoryStreamManager = new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string data = "This is a sample text message.";
    var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

    using (var memoryStream = recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream())
    {
        memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP doesn't need a memory stream _at all_. You can optimise it, sure, but the best solution is _stop using it altogether_.

Comment: Best advice, yes. But we still don't know where the actual problem comes from..